# Invalid parameter for Pipeline

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pipeline, random-forest

Implementing my first pipelines, this error being returned: "Invalid parameter randomforestclassifier for estimator Pipeline"

```
skf = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=3, shuffle=True, random_state=SEED)

classifier = Pipeline([
    ('vectorizer', CountVectorizer(max_features=8000, ngram_range=(1, 5))),
    ('clf', RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=10, random_state=15, n_jobs=-1))])

min_samples_leaf = [5, 6, 7, 8]
max_features = [0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7]
rfc_params = {'randomforestclassifier__min_samples_leaf': min_samples_leaf, 
              'randomforestclassifier__max_features':max_features}

class_grid = GridSearchCV(classifier, param_grid = rfc_params, 
                          cv=skf, scoring='roc_auc', n_jobs=-1)
class_grid.fit(X_text, y_text)
```

Answer (score 0):

This helped, 
if somebody know why or another solve - welcome

```
vectorizer = CountVectorizer(max_features=8000, ngram_range=(1, 5)
clf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=10, random_state=15, n_jobs=-1)               
classifier = make_pipeline(vectorizer, clf)
```

Answer (score 0):

This bug is due to a mismatch in the way you name your classifier. You called it "clf" in your Pipeline but refer to "randomforestclassifier" in your "rfc_params".

Just replace "randomforestclassifier" by "clf" in the "rfc_params" dictionary and it will work.

Working example:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedKFold, GridSearchCV
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

X_text = ["first text", "text", "text", "last text"]
y_text = [0, 1, 0, 1]

skf = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=2, shuffle=True, random_state=42)

classifier = Pipeline([
    ('vectorizer', CountVectorizer(max_features=8000, ngram_range=(1, 5))),
    ('clf', RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=10, random_state=15, n_jobs=-1))])

min_samples_leaf = [5, 6, 7, 8]
max_features = [0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7]

rfc_params = {
    'clf__min_samples_leaf': min_samples_leaf, 
    'clf__max_features':max_features
}

class_grid = GridSearchCV(classifier, param_grid = rfc_params, 
                          cv=skf, scoring='roc_auc', n_jobs=-1)
class_grid.fit(X_text, y_text)
```